# Stop Unity UI Buttons from being clicked when a Facebook Window is overlayed

Tags: unity, facebook, gui

Having an odd issue. When I play with the Facebook SDK for Unity, and the Windows popup like the login window or the Friend Selector window, if I use the mouse to click in the window I end up clicking the Unity 4.6 UI buttons underneath it. Anyone know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display/activate the Facebook SDK popup disable the Unity UI under it until the facebook popup completes.

You might need to reorganize the UI tree to easily deactivate everything but the FB UI by splitting it in two.

Answer (score 0):

There is several different ways to accomplish this task, I found the best way for me was to use a bool and if statement like if(!PauseManager.paused) You could do something like if(!LoginPanelActive) or something then if it is paused or active the buttons just won't trigger and will not until you want them to again. This will also block drags across mobile amongst other bugs you may encounter going a different route.